# Python how to stop the atom-beautify package from line splitting?

Tags: python, atom-editor, atom-beautify

I'm creating a program to get my work schedule from the google calendar API and calculate my pay. There is this one line that keeps on splitting when I don't want it to.

I looked into it a little and increased the preferred line length because I read something in the beautify settings about that's where it got the config for line length, but that didn't work, the text still wrapped.

```
print("\n")
id_key = int(input("Please enter the number of the work calendar:"))
pay_date = int(
    input("Please enter the pay date you want to calculate:"))
print("\n")
```

v.s.

```
print("\n")
id_key = int(input("Please enter the number of the work calendar:"))
pay_date = int(input("Please enter the pay date you want to calculate:"))
print("\n")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Package settings -> Atom Beautify -> Python. Set "Max line length" to whatever value you prefer.